# Excel Writing becomes slow after writing more than 5000 rows in JAVA

Tags: java

It will write slow in excel after writing 5000 rows in excel file.

**Can anyone suggest that how can i speed up writing excelfile?**

I'm **scraping** data from my website with selenium - java

When i start my code, Writing speed is fast, but it becomes slow after 1 hour. (CPU and RAM consumption are normal.)

This is the code for writing excel file.

```
public boolean setCellData(String sheetName,String colName,int rowNum, String data){
        try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(path); 
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        if(rowNum<=0)
            return false;

        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        int colNum=-1;
        if(index==-1)
            return false;


        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);


        row=sheet.getRow(0);
        for(int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++){
            //System.out.println(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim());
            if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName)) {
                colNum=i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(colNum==-1)
            return false;

        sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum); 
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum-1);
        if (row == null)
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum-1);

        cell = row.getCell(colNum); 
        if (cell == null)
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);


        cell.setCellValue(data);

        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);

        workbook.write(fileOut);

        fileOut.close();    

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's see:

- Load entire worksheet into memory
- Update *one* cell
- Write entire worksheet back to file
- Repeat all that for next row/cell

Now why would that be slow?
Because reading and writing files is slow.

You should:

- Load the sheet once
- Update all the rows/cells that need updating
- Save the result back to file

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to the sheet and row, instead of looking them up each time you set a value.